# How could I add padding to span's contents using css (not JS) in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, row, containers, padding, html

I've a bootstrap site, where I defined a background image for BODY, size=cover; which works fine in almost all modern browsers.

Then I've defined a structure like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="span5">CONTACT_FORM_CONTENT</div>
        <div class="span5">MAP_ETC_CONTENT</div>
        <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, some shots to see how it looks:

While viewing in desktop browser
[image: desktop view]

While viewing in smartphone
[image: smartphone view]

**The problem**

While viewing the website in desktop browser, all is ok. Each "< span1 >" at left/right act as padding at left/right correctly, but when viewing with smartphone, these "< span1 >" are transformed and placed at top/bottom of my content and padding at left/right dissapears.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this without using JS? I'd like to correct the entire website with just some css changes.

Thanks

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/ercabq Check this link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this by padding the Form Content like this:

CSS:

```
.padded { padding: 10px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="span5">
            <div class="padded">
                 CONTACT_FORM_CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">MAP_ETC_CONTENT</div>
        <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Hai. Your solution is the ideal, but I wanted to avoid changing 50+ files' code. I thought maybe by modding some boostrap.css code everything could change automatically

Comment: In that case, you can override the span5 class, but that would change every span5 - not sure that's good.  
For example: .span5 {
width: 450px;
padding: 0 10px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your div.row in a div.container. No CSS needed. Now when you go to mobile and it collapses the empty div's, the .container class will maintain padding around your div's. This is ideal, since it gets rid of the excess whitespace to take advantage of screen space, but maintains padding.

Also, there's no need for the div.span1's with empty content. Instead, remove them, and add an .offset1 to your first div.span5.

Also, when nesting span's in another span, you need to enclose it in another div.row. But in this case we can drop the div.span12 entirely, since the inner row adds up to 12 (Bootstrap is "left" aligned, so you don't have to implicitly fill space to the right, and counts towards your total of 12 cells).

And if you want a span12 further down the page, just add another div.row underneath, followed with a div.span12. They only need be contained in the div.container. Style the div.container to add your background color.

If you want to adjust the padding on the div.container, you're really going to want to edit the Bootstrap LESS files, which is another ball of wax and learning curve. Adjusting padding directly throws a bunch of other measurements out of whack, and you'd end up needing to adjust a bunch of stuff to compensate. But I think you'll find the default padding suitable.

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:white;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span5 offset1">CONTACT_FORM_CONTENT</div>
        <div class="span5">MAP_ETC_CONTENT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```